# Is it possible to predefine queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

As the title says, can I predefine some result sets in **MySQL** (as it is evaluated from inner level to outer level) and reuse them later in a query?

I have an example query here (Don't be scared by the size):

```
SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, gamemodeId, mapId FROM
        (
            (SELECT * FROM
            (
                SELECT
                ll.id AS id, ll.globalId AS globalId, ll.date AS date, ll.serverId AS serverId, ll.gamemodeId AS gamemodeId, ll.mapId AS mapId, origin
                FROM
                (
                        (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerjoins' AS origin
                        FROM playerjoins pj
                        WHERE playerId = 976)
                    UNION ALL
                        (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerleaves' AS origin
                        FROM playerleaves pl
                        WHERE playerId = 976)
                    ORDER BY date DESC
                ) pjl
                JOIN levelsloaded ll
                ON pjl.date <= ll.date
                GROUP BY ll.id
                ORDER BY ll.date DESC
            ) above
            WHERE origin = 'playerjoins')
        UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                    ll.id AS id, ll.globalId AS globalId, ll.date AS date, ll.serverId AS serverId, ll.gamemodeId AS gamemodeId, ll.mapId AS mapId, origin
                    FROM
                    (
                            (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerjoins' AS origin
                            FROM playerjoins pj
                            WHERE playerId = 976)
                        UNION ALL
                            (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerleaves' AS origin
                            FROM playerleaves pl
                            WHERE playerId = 976)
                        ORDER BY date DESC
                    ) pjl
                    JOIN levelsloaded ll
                    ON pjl.date >= ll.date
                    GROUP BY ll.id
                    ORDER BY ll.date DESC
                ) below
            WHERE origin = 'playerleaves')
        ) total
        ORDER BY date DESC
```

I'd like to somehow predefine `pjl`:

```
            (
                    (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerjoins' AS origin
                    FROM playerjoins pj
                    WHERE playerId = 976)
                UNION ALL
                    (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerleaves' AS origin
                    FROM playerleaves pl
                    WHERE playerId = 976)
                ORDER BY date DESC
            ) pjl
```

I am using it twice in my full query. I am imaging something like at the start of the query
 `pjl = (...)`, and then in the rest of the code you can just use `pjl`. It should only be valid for the lifetime of the query though.

I could see some problems happening though if it's being defined using a multi-row query (with `;`) in PHP/MySQL setups for example.

Comment: maybe you need a view?

Comment: @fthiella A view however is valid longer as the query. I'm afraid it will impact the performance negatively.

Comment: okay...so you don't want your subquery to be evaluated twice?

Comment: @fthiella I assume the RMDBS is smart enough to not evaluate it twice. I just want to be able to enter it once in the query itself.

Comment: MySQL is not always smart enough.... :)

Comment: Sounds like you need a [materialized view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view).

Comment: Why would a view impact performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a Procedure in MySQL (or possibly a Function): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html